# How to create a dictionary from arrays in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to create a dictionary exactly like this:
Don't worry about contents.

```
 {'image': array([[[238, 238, 239, ..., 226, 227, 230],
     [234, 238, 240, ..., 226, 227, 225],
     [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]],
     ...,
     [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
     [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
     [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
my_dict = {'image': np.array([[[238...]]])}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to work on:

```
dict(zip(keys, zip(*array)))
```

Comment: What is `keys`? What is `array`? What are you trying to do with the `zip` functions and how does this answer address the question asked? Please take a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [[[1,2],[2,3]],[[1]]]
data = {"image": array}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.